# rails activerecord return array of results by comparing 2 tables from 2 different databses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am working on this existing rails application where I am accessing 2 tables from 2 different databases.

```
scope :comp_ids_in, lambda {|comp_ids| where(:comp_id => comp_ids)}

company_info = CompanyInfo.comp_ids_in(my_array_of_ids)
```

the above company_info returns back an an array of ActiveRecord:Relation CompanyInfo objects.

Now I want to compare the above company_info objects with another table on a different database
and return back all the found results in an object.

My existing attempt in my controller would return back only 1 result at a time.

```
company_info.each do |info|
    # RemoteInfo is an acive record class which accesses record from a different database
    remote_info = RemoteInfo.where(username: current_user.username, property_code: info.org_id, chain_code: info.site_id)
end
```

I want all the results stored in the remote_info object. So that I can loop through that object and get any information that was returned.

I would appreciate it if some one can suggest me an efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about the order, it would be efficient to just make one query to get all the remote info

```
remote_info = RemoteInfo.where(username: current_user.username, property_code: company_info.collect(&:org_id), chain_code: company_info.collect(&:site_id))
```